# Javascript capitalizing string after 2 characters

Tags: javascript, string, formatting

I have an address that looks like this:
3513 Jones Drive Apt #500a

How do I capitalize any characters that come after Ap to be all caps. Including the a after the apartment number.

3513 Jones Drive APT #500A

I started using indexOf! Any help is appreciated.

```
NewAddress = toggleCaseText(GetRecordsLF_Address); //3513 Jones Drive Apt #500a
FinalAddress = NewAddress.substring(NewAddress.indexOf('Ap') + 1); //needs to be 3513 Jones Drive APT #500A
```

Comment: what about `43 Apple Blossom Rd.`

Comment: And what about "3513 Jones Drive Suite 500a" ?   Or what if a user left their caps lock on and submitted "3513 jONES dRIVE aPT 500a" ?

Comment: there are services that can help normalize addresses

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression replacement with a callback function that converts the match to uppercase.

```js
let NewAddress = '3513 Jones Drive Apt #500a';
let FinalAddress = NewAddress.replace(/Ap.*/, match => match.toUpperCase());
console.log(FinalAddress);
```

Comment: I get a syntax error when doing this   FinalAddress = NewAddress.replace(/Ap.*/, match => match.toUpperCase());

Comment: Are you using an old version of node.js that doesn't have arrow functions?

Comment: yes a very old version i cant use console.log() to call back in this system where development is occurring

Comment: Then just replace the arrow function with a traditional function.`function(match) { return match.toUpperCase(); }`

Comment: This has false positives, such as `10 Apple Tree Ct.` resulting in `10 APPLE TREE CT.`

Comment: @PeterThoeny That's a problem with the OP's specification, not my implementation. Parsing addresses is a complex problem, not easily solved with a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex replace:

```js
[
  '3513 Jones Drive APT #500A',
  '351 Jones Drive Apt #500a',
  '35 Jones Drive AP #500B',
  '3 Jones Drive Ap #500b',
  '3513 Jones Drive App #500A', // no match
  '43 Apple Blossom Rd.' // no match
].forEach(function(str) {
  var fixed = str.replace(/\bAPT?\b.*/i, function(m) {
    return m.toUpperCase();
  });
  console.log(str + ' => ' + fixed);
});
```

Output:

```
3513 Jones Drive APT #500A => 3513 Jones Drive APT #500A
351 Jones Drive Apt #500a => 351 Jones Drive APT #500A
35 Jones Drive AP #500B => 35 Jones Drive AP #500B
3 Jones Drive Ap #500b => 3 Jones Drive AP #500B
3513 Jones Drive App #500A => 3513 Jones Drive App #500A
43 Apple Blossom Rd. => 43 Apple Blossom Rd.
```

Explanation of regex:

- `\b` -- word boundary
- `AP` -- expect literal `AP`
- `T?` -- optional `T`
- `\b` -- word boundary
- `.*` -- catch everything to end of string
- `/i` -- ignore case

You might want to make the regex more strict to avoid false positives, such as `/\bAPT?\b +#?\w+/i`

**Update:** Changed code for older JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Codestarwik: Does this answer your question? If so would you care to accept it? If not, please add some more details to your question.

Answer (score -2):

```js
let NewAddress = '3513 Jones Drive Apt #500a';
let FinalAddress = NewAddress.replace(/Ap.*/, match => match.toUpperCase());
console.log(FinalAddress);
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the answer I posted over a half hour ago.